# Are Paragon Path powers considered class powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, paragon-path

Example: I have a Warlock with the feat 'Sacrifice to Caiphon', which reads thusly:

> When you attack with a Warlock attack power that has targets and you
>   miss all targets, then you can deal damage to yourself equal to the
>   level of the power. If you do so, you immediately recover the power.

I have the Umbral Cabalist Paragon Path, with the level 11 power Command of the Abyss.
It is listed as an "Umbral Cabalist power", not a Warlock power.

Can I recover it on a miss with Sacrifice to Caiphon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** As you stated, Sacrifice to Caiphon requires a Warlock attack power, and powers from Paragon Paths, Skill Powers, etc. are not Warlock powers.

If it was supposed to, it would have stated something like "Warlock or Warlock Paragon Path Powers," like *Kelgore's Well of Power* (emphasis mine):

> [...]  Instead, the next time you make an attack with a **wizard attack power or a wizard paragon path attack power** before the end of your next turn, the attack deals 2d10 extra damage.